# Alternative for Base64 on Java 1.6?

Tags: java, base64, java-6

If a third service call my program and then i test the string with Base64 and i secret key that i have defined as static. But my program run with java 1.6  (base64 work on 1.8). There are any alternative?
(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: I'm not sure if it runs on java 6 but take a look at Apache commons-codec library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Java library provides base64 encoding/decoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413169/which-java-library-provides-base64-encoding-decoding)